# Every sequence of a closed set converges in the set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I have a doubt when saying if the following assertion is true or false: "Let $F$ be a closed set of a normed vector space $X$. Then every sequence of elements of $F$ converges to an element in $F$".

One one hand, I drafted this proof which states that the assertion is true:

Let consider a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of elements of $F$ which converges to $l \in X \backslash F$.

Then, $\forall r \geq 0, \exists N_r \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N_r, x_n \in \mathcal{B}(l,r)$.

Since $x_n \in F$, and $x_n \in \mathcal{B}(l,r)$, $F \cap \mathcal{B}(l,r) \neq \emptyset$.

So $X \backslash F$ is not open. So $F$ is not closed.

So by a contraposed reasoning, $F$ is closed.

On the other, if I take $[-1,1]$ in $(\mathbb{R}, (\lvert . \rvert )$ and consider the sequence $((-1)^n)_n$ whose elements are in $[-1,1]$, then the sequence diverges, which makes the assertion false.

**EDIT**: I think I've found my mistake. The assertion is false. My proof assumes that the sequence is convergent. Could you confirm?

Comment: Every *covergent* sequence in $F$ converges to a point in $F$ if $F$ is closed. Like your edit states, you were missing that point.

Comment: @GhostAmarth Ok awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement should read: let $F$ be a closed set of a normed vector space $X$. Then any *convergent* sequence of elements from $F$ converges to an element of $F$.

The last could  also be stated as

> If $\{x_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \subseteq F$ and there is some $x \in X$ such that $x_n \to x$, then $x \in F$.

which might be clearer, and in fact holds for any closed set $F$ in any topological space.